# Can not connect to the Service chromedriver

Tags: python, pandas, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to launch the chrome via below python code but it is giving error Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

Chrome_opt  = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Comment: did you download chromedriver.exe?

Comment: Yes,it is already in C drive.